# Referencing column alias in JOIN ON clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a Query is the next:

```
select upper(vchPaterno+' '+vchMaterno+' '+vchNombre) as Nombre
from LK_REP.db_intranet.[dbo].[Empleado_tb] p2 inner join
    LK_SAP.[P01].[p01].[PA0001] p1
    on p1.SNAME = p2.Nombre
```

It's possible make this JOIN?

If I execute this the error message is:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'Nombre'.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. The alias is not bound until later in the processing. You can use "Nombre" in an ORDER BY, but not in a WHERE clause and certainly not in a JOIN clause.

Comment: replace `p2.nombre` by `upper(vchPaterno+' '+vchMaterno+' '+vchNombre)`

Comment: Side note, if you have NULL in any of those three columns you will get NULL for Nombre.

Comment: Is there anything in SQL, where we create an in-memory temporary column (with agg/concat etc. function) for such a requirement and then we can use that column in Join or where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an alias to reference a column, unless it's in your `ORDER BY`

Try this:

```
SELECT UPPER(vchPaterno+' '+vchMaterno+' '+vchNombre) as Nombre
FROM LK_REP.db_intranet.[dbo].[Empleado_tb] p2 
INNER JOIN LK_SAP.[P01].[p01].[PA0001] p1
    ON p1.SNAME = UPPER(vchPaterno+' '+vchMaterno+' '+vchNombre)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat the expression:

```
select upper(p2.vchPaterno + ' ' + p2.vchMaterno+' ' + p2.vchNombre) as Nombre
from LK_REP.db_intranet.[dbo].[Empleado_tb] p2 inner join
     LK_SAP.[P01].[p01].[PA0001] p1
     on p1.SNAME = upper(p2.vchPaterno + ' ' + p2.vchMaterno+' ' + p2.vchNombre);
```

That is the simplest method.  For this problem, I would recommend that you add the column as a computed column into the table:

```
alter table LK_REP.db_intranet.[dbo].[Empleado_tb]
    add nombre as (upper(p2.vchPaterno + ' ' + p2.vchMaterno+' ' + p2.vchNombre) persisted;

create index idx_Empleado_tb_nombre on LK_REP.db_intranet.[dbo].[Empleado_tb](nombre);
```

A computed column and index is good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use columns made in AS not here. In the join in you need a column name (the foreign key)